# Conky has no transparency

Tags: unity, desktop-background, conky

Can't find an awnser to this. I have no idea why Conky isn't working properly. Here's a screenshot:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/09hO01p.png]

Also here's my conky file:

```
**#==============================================================================
#                               conkyrc_orange
#
#  author  : SLK
#  version : v2011011601
#  license : Distributed under the terms of GNU GPL version 2 or later
#
#==============================================================================

background yes
update_interval 1

cpu_avg_samples 2
net_avg_samples 2
temperature_unit celsius

double_buffer yes
no_buffers yes
text_buffer_size 2048

gap_x 10
gap_y 30
minimum_size 190 450
maximum_width 190
own_window yes
own_window_type override
own_window_transparent yes
own_window_argb_visual no
own_window_argb_value 0
own_window_hints undecorate,sticky,skip_taskbar,skip_pager,below
border_inner_margin 0
border_outer_margin 0
alignment tr

draw_shades no
draw_outline no
draw_borders no
draw_graph_borders no

override_utf8_locale yes
use_xft yes
xftfont caviar dreams:size=8
xftalpha 0.5
uppercase no

default_color FFFFFF
color1 DDDDDD
color2 AAAAAA
color3 888888
color4 EF5A29

lua_load ~/.conky/conky_orange.lua
lua_draw_hook_post main

#${voffset 35}
#${goto 95}${color3}${font ubuntu:size=32}${time %e}${color1}${voffset 0}${offset -60}${font ubuntu:size=10}${time %A}
#${goto 85}${color2}${voffset -2}${font ubuntu:size=9}${time %b}${voffset -2} ${color3}${font ubuntu:size=12}${time %Y}${font}
#
#${voffset 70}


TEXT
${voffset 35}
${goto 95}${color4}${font ubuntu:size=22}${time %e}${color1}${offset -50}${font ubuntu:size=10}${time %A}
${goto 85}${color2}${voffset -2}${font ubuntu:size=9}${time %b}${voffset -2} ${color3}${font ubuntu:size=12}${time %Y}${font}

${voffset 80}
${goto 90}${font Ubuntu:size=7,weight:bold}${color}CPU
${goto 90}${font Ubuntu:size=7,weight:normal}${color1}${top name 1}${alignr}${top cpu 1}%
${goto 90}${font Ubuntu:size=7,weight:normal}${color2}${top name 2}${alignr}${top cpu 2}%
${goto 90}${font Ubuntu:size=7,weight:normal}${color3}${top name 3}${alignr}${top cpu 3}%
${goto 90}${cpugraph 10,100 666666 666666}
${goto 90}${voffset -10}${font Ubuntu:size=7,weight:normal}${color}${threads} process 

${voffset 20}
${goto 90}${font Ubuntu:size=7,weight:bold}${color}MEM
${goto 90}${font Ubuntu:size=7,weight:normal}${color1}${top_mem name 1}${alignr}${top_mem mem 1}%
${goto 90}${font Ubuntu:size=7,weight:normal}${color2}${top_mem name 2}${alignr}${top_mem mem 2}%
${goto 90}${font Ubuntu:size=7,weight:normal}${color3}${top_mem name 3}${alignr}${top_mem mem 3}%

${voffset 15}
${goto 90}${font Ubuntu:size=7,weight:bold}${color}DISKS

${goto 90}${diskiograph 30,100 666666 666666}${voffset -30}
${goto 90}${font Ubuntu:size=7,weight:normal}${color}used: ${fs_used /home} /home
${goto 90}${font Ubuntu:size=7,weight:normal}${color}used: ${fs_used /} /

${voffset 10}
${goto 70}${font Ubuntu:size=18,weight:bold}${color3}NET${alignr}${color2}${font Ubuntu:size=7,weight:bold}${color1}${if_up eth0}eth ${addr eth0} ${endif}${if_up wlan0}wifi ${addr wlan0}${endif}
${goto 90}${font Ubuntu:size=7,weight:bold}${color}open ports: ${alignr}${color2}${tcp_portmon 1 65535 count}
${goto 90}${font Ubuntu:size=7,weight:bold}${color}${offset 10}IP${alignr}DPORT
${goto 90}${font Ubuntu:size=7,weight:normal}${color1}${tcp_portmon 1 65535 rip  0}${alignr 1}${tcp_portmon 1 65535 rport  0}
${goto 90}${font Ubuntu:size=7,weight:normal}${color1}${tcp_portmon 1 65535 rip  1}${alignr 1}${tcp_portmon 1 65535 rport  1}
${goto 90}${font Ubuntu:size=7,weight:normal}${color1}${tcp_portmon 1 65535 rip  2}${alignr 1}${tcp_portmon 1 65535 rport  2}
${goto 90}${font Ubuntu:size=7,weight:normal}${color1}${tcp_portmon 1 65535 rip  3}${alignr 1}${tcp_portmon 1 65535 rport  3}
${goto 90}${font Ubuntu:size=7,weight:normal}${color1}${tcp_portmon 1 65535 rip  4}${alignr 1}${tcp_portmon 1 65535 rport  4}
${goto 90}${font Ubuntu:size=7,weight:normal}${color1}${tcp_portmon 1 65535 rip  5}${alignr 1}${tcp_portmon 1 65535 rport  5}
${goto 90}${font Ubuntu:size=7,weight:normal}${color1}${tcp_portmon 1 65535 rip  6}${alignr 1}${tcp_portmon 1 65535 rport  6}
${goto 90}${font Ubuntu:size=7,weight:normal}${color1}${tcp_portmon 1 65535 rip  7}${alignr 1}${tcp_portmon 1 65535 rport  7}
${goto 90}${font Ubuntu:size=7,weight:normal}${color1}${tcp_portmon 1 65535 rip  8}${alignr 1}${tcp_portmon 1 65535 rport  8}
${goto 90}${font Ubuntu:size=7,weight:normal}${color1}${tcp_portmon 1 65535 rip  9}${alignr 1}${tcp_portmon 1 65535 rport  9}
${goto 90}${font Ubuntu:size=7,weight:normal}${color1}${tcp_portmon 1 65535 rip 10}${alignr 1}${tcp_portmon 1 65535 rport 10}
${goto 90}${font Ubuntu:size=7,weight:normal}${color1}${tcp_portmon 1 65535 rip 11}${alignr 1}${tcp_portmon 1 65535 rport 11}
${goto 90}${font Ubuntu:size=7,weight:normal}${color1}${tcp_portmon 1 65535 rip 12}${alignr 1}${tcp_portmon 1 65535 rport 12}
${goto 90}${font Ubuntu:size=7,weight:normal}${color1}${tcp_portmon 1 65535 rip 13}${alignr 1}${tcp_portmon 1 65535 rport 13}
${goto 90}${font Ubuntu:size=7,weight:normal}${color1}${tcp_portmon 1 65535 rip 14}${alignr 1}${tcp_portmon 1 65535 rport 14}

**
```

Comment: looks like unity is lacking transparency as well

Comment: I thought it was supposed to look like that. It always has looked like that for me. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the "own_window_argb_visual" parameter to "yes" and the "own_window_argb_value" parameter to 150 (Valid range is 0-255, where 0 is 0% opacity, and 255 is 100% opacity.).